# Save all images from web page in Java

Tags: java, image

I'm writing a little project and there is a part that I have to download all images from different web pages.
I tried a code that I've found in the solution and it still not working for me.
The code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTML;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;
import javax.swing.text.html.parser.ParserDelegator;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument;

public class ExtractAllImages {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        String webUrl = "https://www.pexels.com/search/HD%20wallpaper/";
        URL url = new URL(webUrl);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        HTMLEditorKit htmlKit = new HTMLEditorKit();
        HTMLDocument htmlDoc = (HTMLDocument) htmlKit.createDefaultDocument();
        htmlKit.read(br, htmlDoc, 0);

        for (HTMLDocument.Iterator iterator = htmlDoc.getIterator(HTML.Tag.A); iterator.isValid(); iterator.next()) {
            AttributeSet attributes = iterator.getAttributes();
            String imgSrc = (String) attributes.getAttribute(HTML.Attribute.HREF);

            System.out.println(imgSrc);
            if (imgSrc != null && (imgSrc.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg") || (imgSrc.endsWith(".png")) || (imgSrc.endsWith(".jpeg")) || (imgSrc.endsWith(".bmp")) || (imgSrc.endsWith(".ico")))) {
                try {
                    downloadImage(webUrl, imgSrc);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private static void downloadImage(String url, String imgSrc) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage image = null;
        try {
            if (!(imgSrc.startsWith("http"))) {
                url = url + imgSrc;
            } else {
                url = imgSrc;
            }
            imgSrc = imgSrc.substring(imgSrc.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            String imageFormat = null;
            imageFormat = imgSrc.substring(imgSrc.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
            String imgPath = null;
            imgPath = "C:/Check/" + imgSrc + "";
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            image = ImageIO.read(imageUrl);
            if (image != null) {
                File file = new File(imgPath);
                ImageIO.write(image, imageFormat, file);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

The error I get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP
>   response code: 403 for URL:
>   https://www.pexels.com/search/HD%20wallpaper/     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)   at ExtractAllImages.main(ExtractAllImages.java:23)

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit**:
I've tried other web pages and sometimes there is no error at all and still no image save to my path.
On some web pages I got this error:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.swing.text.ChangedCharSetException
>     at javax.swing.text.html.parser.DocumentParser.handleEmptyTag(Unknown
>   Source)   at javax.swing.text.html.parser.Parser.startTag(Unknown
>   Source)   at javax.swing.text.html.parser.Parser.parseTag(Unknown
>   Source)   at javax.swing.text.html.parser.Parser.parseContent(Unknown
>   Source)   at javax.swing.text.html.parser.Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
>     at javax.swing.text.html.parser.DocumentParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>     at javax.swing.text.html.parser.ParserDelegator.parse(Unknown Source)
>     at javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit.read(Unknown Source)     at
>   ExtractAllImages.main(ExtractAllImages.java:29)

Any other way to write this code?

Comment: That code works if the site doesn't actively block such  requests... *HTTP 403 Forbidden client error status response code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it*

Comment: When I try it on other web pages there is no error but nothing happen.

Comment: Again, this website is blocking your requests. I can't speak for other sites, but what are you expecting to happen? Is `"C:/Check/` empty?

Comment: Yes, I've tried some web pages and the code works fine without errors but no image saving at all

Comment: Well, on windows, filepaths are like C:\\path\\, not sure that fixes anything though

Comment: still not working..

Comment: I think you should place an else statement onto `if (image != null) {` and print some conditions. Else, start the debugger in your IDE

Comment: Have a suggestion how to write it exactly?

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP error 403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) means that server refused request from client. Often you can bypass such check by introducing your client as someone else, by changing [user-agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) value.

To change user-agent you can call this (e.g. in first line of your code):

```
System.setProperty("http.agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36");
```

After this change your application will be able to connect to mentioned page (or similar) without problem because it will introduce as Chrome browser.

Anyway, there are few other issues in your application. While implementing app have in mind this:

1. You are using imgSrc.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg"). In real world many image links doesn't end with .jpg but with parameters, e.g.: https://images.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg?h=350&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb. You should consider at least using `imgSrc.toLowerCase().contains(".jpg")` method.
2. Images are added to web page using [img](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) tag. In that case you should search for `img` tags and get src `property` in which path to image is set.
3. In case of `www.pexels.com`, when you click on wallpaper you are redirected to second page where you can download the wallpaper. Your application is trying to download images from primary page. You should first open second page and download desired image from there.

Comment: I'm pretty confused but I've added the user-agent line in first line like you said.
I changed the imgSrc to contains instead of endsWith I try it and nothing happen.
My target in this code is to download all images the web page got right now.

Comment: It sound as there is lack of knowledge and unfortunately requirement is too complex to explain it easily. You will need to test and debug code by your own. When you hit to a problem ask and we will try to help you. I tried to answer your initial question and give you some hints. It is up to you to do a research and ask more specific questions than "nothing happened".